# ng commands throws insufficient memory error [Fatal process OOM in insufficient memory to create an Isolate]

Tags: angular, npm, out-of-memory, angular-cli

When I run any angular command (ng command), I am getting insufficient memory error. But there is enough memory (RAM & Heap) in my system. The npm version is 6.4.1.

```
ng version or ng create or ng build
```

Getting the following error as:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->


<--- JS stacktrace --->


#
# Fatal process OOM in insufficient memory to create an Isolate
#
```

Comment: it should be `ng version`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez, we can use ng -v or ng -version

Comment: yes.. it can be ng -v also

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm running into this problem after bumping `max_old_space_size` up from 5GB to 8GB. Before doing that I was getting the typical JS out of heap error but this one is different and only started after I bumped the size up to 8GB. Curious what the solution was for you?

Answer (score 2):

By default the memory limit in Node.js is 512 mb.

You need to run:

> `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=30720`

(*) Refer [here](https://medium.com/@vuongtran/how-to-solve-process-out-of-memory-in-node-js-5f0de8f8464c) if you want more information.

Answer (score 0):

As per the list of commands (which can be seen using `ng help`). You should use `ng -v` to get the version you are using for Angular.

[image]

Comment: we can use ng -v or ng v or ng -version. All the commands throwing the same error

Comment: @SinuVarghese, please take a look at the documentation on https://angular.io/cli/version

Comment: It is not the issue of syntax of the command. All the commands(ng v or ng version or ng -v or ng -version) throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by re-installing nodejs.